# CNN: correlation between filter size and stride

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

Unet is a pretty popular network architecture, used in various computer vision tasks. Commonly, Unet encoder has downsampling layers that downsample by 2, which means the stride of the conv layer used will be 2 and filter sizes >3.
For a problem that I am trying, I want to perform downsampling 8 times ( by 2 each time). Instead of having 8 layers in the encoder, I thought I can have 4 layers that downsample by 4 each. For this, I dont think filter sizes like 3 or 5 make much sense- during the sliding, the filter will end up not covering certain pixels.
I would like to get some pointers on how I need to alter the filter size as I alter stride and vice-versa. Additionally, would it also make sense to reduce the number of filters if I increase filter size?

A pointer to the readers of this Q: I searched the internet for prior works that use stride 4, and found AlexNet. Its first conv layer has filters `11x11x96` and `stride 4`. So, I am encouraged to increase my filter size. :)

Comment: I would suggest you use max-pooling (alongside striding or not), it"s the old way of downscaling.It has the advantage that it does not require any convolution to work with :) You could do conv - max_pool(4)-conv-max_pool(4) ...

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question right? When using max pool 4, what is a better kernel size? 3 or 5 or 7 or 9 or 11?

Comment: If you want overlapping convolutions you will need kernels larger than the stride value. It depends on how much correlation you want between each convolution operation; a larger overlap gives you more "attributes" or "features" but they are correlated and smaller overlap prevents that. Which also means that large overlap may encourage overfitting. So it's a trade-off according to me. I hope you can find your perfect kernel size.

Also there might be implications on the corresponding transposed-convolution layer for your U-Net. You will definitely find more perspectives on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this fits your problem. But if you want to downsampling 8 times and avoid the problem of strides, you can set the padding to "same" in the Conv2D layers. It will apply the stride and padding with zeros evenly to the left/right or up/down of the input such that output has the same height/width dimension as the input.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).